# Need Help preg_match the word dot

Tags: preg-match

I am trying to stop people from posting munged email addresses in their profiles on my site. I use preg_match to get most of the munging except I am having issues with the word "dot". I am loosing it at this point and need help since neither of these two work see below.

```
  if (preg_match("/^dot$/", $cko)) 
       { 
          $errors ++;
                $message .= '<font color="red">blah</font><br  />'; 
       }    

         if (preg_match("/\bdot\b/", $cko))
       { 
          $errors ++;
                $message .= '<font color="red">blah</font><br />'; 
       }
```

Okay I was loosing it. I found my answer by adding an i to the code below.

```
    if (preg_match("/\bdot\b/i", $cko))
       { 
          $errors ++;
                $message .= '<font color="red">blah</font><br />'; 
       }
```